# Cancelling PendingIntent crashes application

Tags: java, android

I've set an Alarm using `PendingIntent` and now I want to cancel the alarm. However trying to do so, crashes the entire application.

Here is how I set the Alarm:

```
private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal)
{
    Intent alarmintent = new Intent(AddAlarm.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    alarmintent.putExtra("ALARM_NO", tempx);
    alarmintent.setAction("my.action.string");
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AddAlarm.this, pen, alarmintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);


}
```

> where pen is the UniqueId

Now here is where I get error when I cancel the Alarm.

```
public void alarmSet1(View view)
{
    //ToggleButton Toggler = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.alarm1);
    int a1=1;
    int idTime = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = times.edit();
    editor.putInt("ID1", idTime);
    editor.commit();
    if (((ToggleButton) view).isChecked()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddAlarm.class);
        intent.putExtra("pendInt", idTime);
        intent.putExtra("tts", a1);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    else
    {


        int rec = times.getInt("ID1",0);


        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this,
                rec, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        pendingIntent.cancel();
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

    }
}
```

Here is the logcat as well :

```
> 07-29 20:19:06.198  14220-14220/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia, PID: 14220
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4020)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:120)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:120)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.AlarmManager.cancel(android.app.PendingIntent)' on a null object reference
            at zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia.MainActivity.alarmSet1(MainActivity.java:150)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:120)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Looking for any fix/solutions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is throwing a NullPointerException:

```
alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

Probably because alarmManager is not initialized. Add this line above the first.

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Doing so fixed the bug, Thank you , But the alarm still plays on  ! :(

Answer (score 1):

`alarmSet1()` does not initialize `alarmManager`, and it is `null`, as indicated by the stack trace. I do not know where you are initializing `alarmManager`. Most likely, you should get rid of `alarmManager` and have both `setAlarm()` and `alarmSet1()` retrieve an `AlarmManager` as needed.

Comment: Super fan of your book, it's first time you are answering my question. Super thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `alarmManager` is not initalized.

Comment: Thanks for answering.